# 16 to 1 mux using 2 to 1 mux in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, digital, xilinx-ise

I'm trying to write a code in vhdl to create a 16 to 1 mux using 2 to 1 mux.
I actually thought that to do this we may need 15 two to one multiplexers and by wiring them together and using structural model I wrote the code below.
First I wrote a 2 to 1 mux:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity MUX_2_1 is
 port (
 w0 , w1 : IN STD_LOGIC;
 SELECT_I: IN std_logic;
 DATA_O: out std_logic
);
end MUX_2_1;
architecture MUX_2_1_arch of MUX_2_1 is
--
begin
--
WITH SELECT_I SELECT
DATA_O <= w0 WHEN '0',
w1 WHEN '1',
'X' when others;
--
end MUX_2_1_arch;
```

and made a package from it, just to use it simple and easy:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

PACKAGE mux2to1_package IS
COMPONENT mux2to1
PORT (w0, w1: IN STD_LOGIC ;
 SELECT_I: IN std_logic;
 DATA_O: out std_logic ) ;
END COMPONENT ;
END mux2to1_package ;
```

and then my 16 to 1 mux looks like this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE work.mux2to1_package.all ;

ENTITY mux16to1 IS
PORT (w : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0) ;
s : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) ;
f : OUT STD_LOGIC ) ;
END mux16to1 ;

ARCHITECTURE Structure OF mux16to1 IS
SIGNAL im : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0) ;
SIGNAL q : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL p : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
Mux1: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( w(0), w(1), s(0), im(0)) ;
Mux2: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( w(2), w(3), s(0), im(1)) ;
Mux3: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( w(4), w(5), s(0), im(2)) ;
Mux4: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( w(6), w(7), s(0), im(3)) ;
Mux5: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( w(8), w(9), s(0), im(4)) ;
MUX6: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( w(10), w(11), s(0), im(5));
Mux7: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( w(12), w(13), s(0), im(6)) ;
Mux8: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( w(14), w(15), s(0), im(7)) ;
Mux9: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( im(0), im(1), s(1), q(0)) ;
Mux10: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( im(2), im(3), s(1), q(1)) ;
Mux11: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( im(4), im(5), s(1), q(2)) ;
Mux12: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( im(6), im(7), s(1), q(3)) ;
Mux13: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( q(0), q(1), s(2), p(0)) ;
Mux14: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( q(2), q(3), s(2), p(1)) ;
Mux15: mux2to1 PORT MAP ( p(0), p(1), s(3), f) ;
END Structure ;
```

and also my testbench is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE work.mux2to1_package.all ;

ENTITY Mux_test IS
END Mux_test;

ARCHITECTURE test OF Mux_test IS

COMPONENT mux16to1 PORT(w : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0) ;
                        s : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) ;
                        f : OUT STD_LOGIC ) ;
END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL wi : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0) ;
SIGNAL selecting : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) ;
SIGNAL fi : STD_LOGIC ;

BEGIN
a1: mux16to1 PORT MAP(wi , selecting , fi);

wi<= "0101110010001010" , "1001000101010101" after 100 ns;
selecting <= "0011" , "1010" after 20 ns , "1110" after 40 ns, "1100" after 60 ns , "0101" after 80 ns,
          "0011" after 100 ns , "1010" after 120 ns , "1110" after 140 ns, "1100" after 160 ns , "0101" after 180 ns;
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

my simulation:
[image]

But when I try to simulate this nothing shows in my output. I'm thinking that maybe that's because I wrote my code in concurrent part and signals `im` and `q` and `p` are not initialized yet so I tried using default values "00000000" for `im` and "0000" for `q` and "00" for `p` when I was declaring the signals, but then I got bunch of errors saying "Instance mux2to1 is unbound" in simulation and nothing actually changed.
Any idea what is the problem??

Also I think there is something wrong with my select input logically.
but I don't understand how i should use the select to be correct for this problem.
I would appreciate if anyone can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual component binding using component declarations can either be explicit using a configuration specification to supply a binding indication, or rely on a default binding indication.

A default binding indication would rely on finding an entity declared in a reference library whose name matches the component name. That's not the case here, your entity is named MUX_2_1 (case insensitive) while the component name is mux2to1.

It's not illegal to have components unbound in VHDL, it's the equivalent of not loading a component in a particular location in a printed circuit or bread board, it simply produces no output which shows in simulation here as a 'U'.

Here the solutions could be to either change the name of the entity in both the entity declaration and it's architecture from MUX_2_1 to mux2to1, change the component declaration to MUX_2_1 or provide a configuration specification providing an explicit binding indication as a block declarative item in the architecture for mux16to1 of the form

```vhdl
ARCHITECTURE Structure OF mux16to1 IS
SIGNAL im : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0) ;
SIGNAL q : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL p : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
for all: mux2to1 use entity work.MUX_2_1;  -- ADDED
```

When used the latter method provides '1' and '0' outputs on testbench signal fi during simulation.

The testbench can be made more elaborate to demonstrate that the selects are valid. One way would be with marching '0's or '1's in w elements while scanning all the elements and looking for a mismatch:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux16to1_tb is
end mux16to1_tb;

architecture test of mux16to1_tb is
    component mux16to1 is
        port (
            w:  in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            s:  in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            f:  out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal w:       std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal s:       std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal f:       std_logic;
    
    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;

begin
    
DUT: 
    mux16to1 
        port map (
            w => w,
            s => s,
            f => f
        );

STIMULI:
    process
        use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    begin
        for i in w'reverse_range loop
            w <= (others => '1');
            w(i) <= '0';
            for j in w'reverse_range loop
                s <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(j, s'length));
                wait for 10 ns;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        wait;
end process;

VALIDATE:
    process
    begin
        for x in w'reverse_range loop
            for y in w'reverse_range loop
                wait for 10 ns;
                assert f = w(y)
                report 
                    LF & HT & "f = " & std_ulogic'image(f) & " " &
                              "expected " & std_ulogic'image(w(y)) &
                    LF & HT & "w = " & to_string(w) &
                    LF & HT & "s = " & to_string(s)
                severity ERROR;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

The output f of mux16to1 is selected for each value of w using a marching '0's pattern. Any mismatch between f and the selected name element value of w is reported with diagnostic information.

Here we see that mux16t01 implements a 16:1 selection properly without the need to modify the original posters design.

Without error injection the testbench waveforms for w, s and f can be viewed in a waveform display to validate correct operation.

Comment: gosh. i was so careless about names. i thought that in such case compiler would interrupt me with errors. but weird that i got no errors about that.  and it actually worked with your solution. thank you so much.

Comment: and also i am wondering can you help me with my second part of problem?? whether the logic of choosing selects is true or not. i have no idea how i should declare them and how to connect them with my multiplexers.

Comment: Your mux16to1 behavior is correct as shown with an expanded testbench.

Comment: thanks alot. now i get what you mean by that.